# How to increment a number when transforming json

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I am trying to increment a version field. Input is

```
{"version":1}
```

Output should be

```
{"v":2}
```

When I do

```
echo '{"version":1}'|jq '{"v":.version+1}'
```

I get

```
error: syntax error, unexpected '+', expecting '}'
```

While adding in string interpolation works

```
echo '{"version":1}'|jq '{"v":"\(.version+1)"}'
```

yields

```
{
  "v":"2"
}
```

I need v to be of number type, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
echo '{"version":1}' | jq '{"v":(.version+1)}'
```

This seems to work on the [playground of jq](https://jqplay.org).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape "+" (plus) with "\+" and see. Like:

```
echo '{"version":1}'|jq '{"v":.version\+1}'
```